# post-receive GIT hook is running from my local machine

Tags: githooks

I have written a simple echo statement in post-receive file present in `.git/hooks`. After me making a push operation I am not able to see the echo statement in my console output. Which means the post-receive server related hook has not been executed.

If I try some local hooks like pre-commit hook those scripts gets executed.

What are the steps that I need to follow to make a server related hook to execute.

Answer (score 0):

`post-receive`, as a [**server-side** hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), does not get executed by clients that are pushing data to servers.

To set up a `post-receive` hook, you will want to modify the hooks of the Git repo *on the server* you're pushing to.  If you are looking to use these hooks to do something on your local client, then you will need to use a client-side hook (or get the server to communicate with the client manually on `post-receive`).  The closest you will get for client-side hooks is the `pre-push` hook (Git does not have a `post-push` hook).

Comment: So Where does that hook reside in server, and how will I be editing it. As I would be having only the GIT Url for pushing in to the master

Comment: The hooks on the server exist in the same relative location as they do in your local client; within the `.git/hooks` folder of the repo location on the server (the point of Git is that it is distributed in nature; there is really no distinction from Git's perspective between what is a client and what is a server).

Comment: So is there a way where in I make changes in my local machine and push the post-receive hook to the server

Comment: You don't "push" hooks, per se (the `.git/hooks/` directory is not under version control of the containing repository).  If you have direct access to the git repository on the server, you can modify the hooks in it.  This will depend on your server though; if you have control over the server this is no problem. If your server is providing Git SaaS (like GitHub/etc.), then you will need to look at their support.

Comment: Can you provide me some links or examples for my better understanding of creating a Post-Recive Git hook. Also Can you help me to understand what is Git SaaS, How do I find-out If the server is providing Git SaaS